# How to find all jpeg files having name without underscore from a specific folder and its subfolders in batch file then rename it

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following script which gets all the files of type .jpg or.png located in the subfolder IN and renamed it with the folder name one layer up from IN which is named after the agent number.

for example, there is this path `\\servername\SECH\DATA\CLI\45\IN\image504.jpeg`, it should rename it to `45_image504.jpeg`.

I want to use for /R because I want it to look only in the subfolders of CLI unless there is another way to pass the location to search in the for  loop. I want to know how this script can be improved to look for jpg files that do not have an underscore in the name.

```
For /R  \\servername\CLI\ %%a in (*.jpg *.png) DO (    echo filename %%~nxa     For %%g in (%%a\..) do ( 
     SET LAST_FOLDER=%%~nxg
     If "!LAST_FOLDER!" == "IN" (
         FOR %%V IN (%%a\..\..) DO (
              SET FOLDER_NAME=%%~nxV
              SET CURRENT_FILE_NAME=%%~nxa
              SET PREFIX=!FOLDER_NAME!_

              echo FOLDER_NAME : !FOLDER_NAME!
              echo CURRENT_FILE_NAME  : !CURRENT_FILE_NAME!
              If "!CURRENT_FILE_NAME:~0,4!" == "!PREFIX!" ( 
                   echo filename exists
               ) Else (
                  Rename "%%~a" "!FOLDER_NAME!_%%~nxa"
              )  
    
         )
      )
                    ) )
```

Comment: In fact it looks like all you need is the single command line `@for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir "\\servername\CLI\*.jpg" "\\servername\CLI\*.jpeg" "\\servername\CLI\*.png" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /C:_') do @for %%H in ("%%~dpG..") do @ren "%%G" "%%~nxH_%%~nxG"` to rename the files not containing already an underscore with folder name and an underscore prepended as long as no folder contains an underscore in its name. There is nothing else needed in the batch file as just this command line for this file rename operation.

Comment: Thank you I was able to make it works @Mofi

Answer (score 0):

Since the target files are located in a certain directory hierarchy depth, you should perhaps not search for them recursively in order to avoid unexpected matches.

Hence I would do it the following way:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=\\servername\SECH\DATA\CLI"      & rem // (full path to target dir.)
set "_SDIR=IN"                              & rem // (name of sub-sub-directory)
set "_VSTR=_"                               & rem // (separator char. or string)
set _MASKS="*.jpg" "*.jpeg" "*.jpe" "*.png" & rem // (list of quoted patterns)

rem // Change into target directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Loop through immediate sub-directories:
    for /D %%E in ("*") do (
        rem // Change into sub-sub-directory:
        pushd "%%~E\%_SDIR%" 2> nul && (
            rem // Loop through matching files, excluding those with separator:
            for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
                dir /B /A:-D-H-S %_MASK% ^| findstr /V /I /C:"%_VSTR%"
            ') do (
                rem // Actually rename the current file:
                ren "%%F" "%%~nxE%_VSTR%%%F"
            )
            rem // Return from sub-sub-directory:
            popd
        )
    )
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```